# Is it possible to "Turn off" or "Turn on" volatility in C variables?

Tags: c, warnings, volatile

I have two static volatile variables in C and I would like to check them both in a logical statement. However, when I do I get a warning " undefined behavior: the order of volatile accesses is undefined in this statement  1037"
Is it possible to suspend volatility of a C variable for a very brief moment to ensure good data?

Here is the code:

```
static volatile unsigned char b;
static volatile unsigned char a;

//update the states of the two volatile variables 
update_vars( &a);
update_vars( &b);

// check them in a logical statement
// Can I suspend the volatile lable??  
if((addr_bit & (a | b)) == 0){
// update another variables
}
else{
// another action
}
```

I'm thinking about this in the same context of interrupts, whereas you temporary suspend them if you want stable evaluation of the data at a precise moment. Thanks!

Comment: C doesn't have any kind of [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). Once a program is built, the types of variables are fixed.

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can use two temporary variables, assign the volatiles to them and then perform the check on those.

Comment: But it looks like you don't need volatile at all, as I see you call `update_vars`.

Comment: What `update_vars` do? I suspect that these should not even be volatile...

Comment: update_vars is checking for the change in a variable value.

Comment: What does it mean? Please post the code.

Comment: It just checks a register and does some filtering. After that there is some IP i cannot post. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does it assign a value to the passed pointer? If it does, then you are misusing `volatile`.

Comment: The weird thing is that you are calling `update_vars` twice, only varying the argument. Does it somehow detect which of `a` and `b` you are passing? And are `a` and `b` registers themselves, and you update some other vars based on them? Or, is `update_vars` reading some other registers and assigning a value through the pointer argument (e.g., `*arg = filter(some_register);`)? In the latter case you probably don't need (and shouldn't use) `volatile` at all – volatility isn't "inherited" from the register being volatile. Does something else assign to `a` and/or `b`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `volatile` property of a variable cannot be disabled.

You need to create a non-volatile copy of each and then operate on those.

```
unsigned char a_stable = a;
unsigned char b_stable = b;

if((addr_bit & (a_stable | b_stable)) == 0){
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the warning you can **break up the C statement, so that each C statement holds only one access to a volatile variable.**